# PostgreSQL condition, where date > "first day of the month"

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

```
WHERE my_timestamp > to_char(date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE),'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00')
```

does not work. How do I achieve a where `date` > "first day of this month"?

Comment: why do you convert the `timestamp` to a `varchar` in order to compare that to a `timestamp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `my_timestamp` is really of type `TIMESTAMP`, `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` or `DATE` then the only thing you need is:

```
WHERE my_timestamp > DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE)
```

and nothing more. If `my_timestamp` is one of text types and this is the reason you used `to_char()` then it's totally wrong. Because what means that one string is greater than other one? For sure string comparision can't define order by dates inside those strings.

**Update (thanks [jpmc26](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1394393/jpmc26) for suggestion):**

If `my_timestamp` is a string then you need to cast it to `TIMESTAMP` rahter than cast `CURRENT_DATE` to string (remember to use time format of `my_timestamp`).

```
WHERE to_timestamp(my_timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE)
```

Comment: You should probably mention what to do in the case that `my_timestamp` is a string type (namely call some variation of `to_timestamp` in it).

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of your `my_timestamp` field?

For `datetime` it works fine:

```
select * from my_table where my_table.date > date_trunc('month', current_date);
```